# Operator overloading with files

Tags: c++

Is there a way in which I can use a operator overloader to output to a file. I understand the code behind the actual outputting to a file but I don't understand how I would actually invoke a overloader to carry out the out to the file
Any help in helping me understand this would be appreciated

Comment: Overload `operator>>` and use an `ofstream`.

Comment: From your question it's really not all that clear what it is you are trying to do, so please clarify a bit.

Comment: @larsmans hehe, guess you get it wrong all the time just like me, heh? It's `operator<<` :)

Comment: I'm trying to get a string to output to a file and i'm trying to do this through a overload operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct A {
    int a;
public:
    std::ostream& save(std::ostream& out) const {
        return out << a;
    }
    std::istream& load(std::istream& in) {
        return in >> a;
    }
};
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const A& obj) {
    return obj.save(out);
}
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, A& obj) {
    return obj.load(in);
}

int main() {  
    A a;
    std::cin >> a;
    std::cout << a;
    return 0;
}
```